# Rspec: Suppress output of test when formatting?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got a very large, very complex test suite. Some aspects of the test suite are unrelated to the spec of the application they are testing - they are simply there to insure that I can easily track down problems with the test itself being incorrect - for example, fixture data being improperly formatted. Essentially, I have a group of tests that exists solely to insure my tests are working correctly.

I WOULD like to see if this stuff fails, for obvious reasons, but I don't want it dirtying up my "specifications" - is there any way to set a test or, even better, a context, to invisible on success?

Answer (score 0):

I think FUBAR, the gem, is the simplest option.  It will make things fail explosively, but otherwise be a simple little status bar.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for here. I only want to suppress the output of certain tests not relevant to the specs, not all of them.

Comment: Huh.  No idea then.  Sorry :-(